# how give placeholder to dropdown box created in yii2 gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have created a dropdown in yii2 gridview in search box
as

```
[
    'attribute'=>'attribute name',
    'filter'=>array("ID1"=>"Name1","ID2"=>"Name2"),
],
```

I tried many ways to give placeholder but cant...
so how to add placeholder??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [filterInputOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$filterInputOptions-detail)

```
[
   'attribute'=>'attribute name',
   'filter'=>array("ID1"=>"Name1","ID2"=>"Name2"),
   'filterInputOptions' => [
       'class' => 'form-control',         
       'prompt' => 'Select Option'
    ],
],
```

Comment: THANKS Its working but field getting small as compared to other search boxes in gridview

Answer (score 0):

Try it,,

```
[
    'attribute'=>'attribute name'
    'filter' =>  Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'attribute name', array("ID1"=>"Name1","ID2"=>"Name2"),['class'=>'form-control','prompt' => 'Select Name']),
]
```

Hope help,,,